# Tentando obter a propriedade 'num_rows'

Tags: php

Não estou conseguindo resolver este erro, estou ha mais de 5 horas programando kkk, deixei passar por algo ?

aqui esta o meu codigo(**esta EM COMENTARIO onde ele fala que é o erro**)

estou fazendo validaçao pra logar em poo

**Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in**

```html
<?php 
//includes


 class User extends Database{

  public function getUser($username,$senha){
   $obj = new conectar();
   $conexao = $obj->conexao();

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$username' AND senha = '$senha'";

   $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);

   
      
      //AQUI ESTA O ERROR
      $numRows = $result->num_rows;
   
      
      if ($numRows == 1) {
    return true;
   }
   return false;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Tenta passar o $result->num_rows direto no if: if ($result->num_rows == 1) ao invés de colocar ele em uma variável;

Se for o caso vc pode verificar o que está vindo dentro dele com um print_r. Pra vc saber se está passando alguma informação.

Comment: tentei, e nada,

Comment: usei o print_r, e ele esta passando as informações

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer login usando PDO eu não uso o count rows, uso o `fetchAll()` e verifico a quantidade de resultados, assim:

```
//SQL Statement
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cadUsuario WHERE email=:email AND senha=:senha");
$query->bindParam(":email", $_POST['email']);
$query->bindParam(":senha", $_POST['senha']);

//Executa a query
$query->execute();

//Retorna os resultados
$usuario = $query->fetchAll();

//Se mais de um resultado, executa o código para login
    if($usuario >0) {
    //código vai aqui
}
```

Pelo manual do PHP, o `fetchAll()`:

> PDOStatement::fetchAll — Retorna um array contendo todas as linhas do
>   resultado

Comment: nesse caso vou tentar ajustar de acordo com o meu codigo,

Comment: Nada, nao foi resolvido